# undefined method when trying to send params from a controller to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I'am having an issue in rails when i'am trying to send params from a controller to another controller when i use:

> CarsControllers.new.create

I'am having this error:

> undefined method `parameters’ for nil:NilClass

and the params that i'am sending go as null
why i'am having this error ?

and i'am sorry i'am still new with ruby on rails

Comment: Are you calling `CarsController.new.create` from another controller? If so, that's the wrong way to go about things.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect a request?

Comment: No one uses this syntax CarsControllers.new.create .Params need to be sent from View.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then I will say you trying to send `params` one controller to another controller, if yes then see the below

```
redirect_to controller: 'Cars', action: 'index', param1: 'value1', foo: 'bar', ...
```

If not this then please clarify your question using more details and tried code.

Hope it helps